# select the first k entries of each group in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, extract

Say I have a csv file, each entry is with a unique ID and a category name. Entries of each category will appear at least k times as specified in the title. Now I want to select the first k entries of each category (I don't know how many categories there are)

**Example**

**original table**

```
 ID.   category
 1.     apple
 2.     apple
 3.     apple
 4.     apple
 5.     orange
 6.     orange
 7.     orange
 8.     banana
 9.     banana
 10.    banana
```

**if k = 2**

**expected output table**

```
 ID.   category
 1.     apple
 2.     apple
 5.     orange
 6.     orange
 8.     banana
 9.     banana
```

Is there a way to do this in Python (like using pandas, etc.)? Currently I haven't came up with an idea to achieve this ... And I didn't find the solution after bunches of search. Only found these using SQL in database and that's not what I want. Thanks!

Comment: is the input file sorted by those categories?

Comment: Yes it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Oh just found this, use pandas, it works!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f_dir)
fd = df.groupby('category').head(2)
print fd
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to keep track of the categories and how often they've been seen:

```
catsSeen = {}
returnList = []
for row in table:
    if row[1] not in catsSeen:
        catsSeen[row[1]] = 1
        returnList.append(row)
    else:
        if catsSeen[row[1]] < 2:
            returnList.append(row)
            catsSeen[row[1]] += 1

print(returnList)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though I just found there's a neat method by using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

if your input files is sorted by those categories you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby):

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from itertools import groupby

txt = '''ID.   category
 1.     apple
 2.     apple
 3.     apple
 4.     apple
 5.     orange
 6.     orange
 7.     orange
 8.     banana
 9.     banana
 10.    banana'''

k = 2

with StringIO(txt) as in_file, StringIO() as out_file:

    data = DictReader(in_file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    out = DictWriter(out_file, delimiter=' ', fieldnames=data.fieldnames)
    out.writeheader()

    for key, items in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['category']):
        for item, _ in zip(items, range(k)):
            out.writerow(item)

    print(out_file.getvalue())  # this is just to print the result...
```

this results in

```
ID. category
1. apple
2. apple
5. orange
6. orange
8. banana
9. banana
```

(you probably have to replace `StringIO` with your input/output files)

`zip(items, range(k))` stops after `k` `items` have been reached or `items` is exhausted - whichever comes first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though I just found there's a neat method by using pandas